# How does $\operatorname{Cov}(X^{T}u)=0$ imply that $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$ is an unbiased estimator

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, linear

Consider the following classical multiple linear regression model:

$y = X\beta +u$

Why does $\operatorname{Cov}(X^{T}u)=0\implies E[\hat{\beta}_{OLS}-\beta]=0$?

Why I do not understand the implication:

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X^{T}u)=E[(X^{T}u)(X^{T}u)^{T}]=E[(X^{T}uu^{T}X)]=X^{T}E[uu^{T}]X=\sigma^{2}X^{T}X $$

and also:

$$\hat{\beta}_{OLS}-\beta=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}u$$

I would understand why $E[X^{T}u]=0\implies E[\hat{\beta}_{OLS}-\beta]=0$ but I do not understand how the assumption on the covariance can lead to an implication

Comment: Your formula for the covariance is incorrect because it implicitly assumes $E[X^\prime u]=0.$